# Reaction Commerce - Mongo Shell import products not showing up

Tags: meteor, reaction-commerce

I'm trying to use the `meteorimport` to import a product and it's many variants into the app.

It's able to import the product that I see show up in the web app, but in the miniMongo chrome extension it doesn't list the imported product or it's variants.

The meteor shell lists them with `db.Products.find()` but when I try to `db.Products.find()` for the specific product ID, nothing results.

Here's the Products.json I'm trying to import: https://gist.github.com/mikeumus/a5133eb710a5aacb0b4dc9e6b5662026

`{ "-id" : "Faux-Wood-Blinds", "title" : "Faux Wood Blinds", "shopId" : "J8Bhq3uTtdgwZx3rz", "ancestors" : [], "createdAt" : Date( 1396558012411 ), 
...`

The `meteorimport` is successful:

`mikeumus@cbc-instance-5:~/rc-ca-blinds$ mongoimport --db meteor --collection Products --file ./fauxwood-cbc-mongodb.json/meteor/Products.json --port 3001 --jsonArray
connected to: 127.0.0.1:3001
2018-03-09T19:29:29.300+0000 check 9 28
2018-03-09T19:29:29.301+0000 imported 28 objects`

Should I not be importing from the meteor mongo shell like this? Can I use [Reaction.import.Object()](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/reaction-import#batch-inserts-and-fixture-data) or [Reaction.import.Product()](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/reaction-import#batch-inserts-and-fixture-data) for this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist shows some issues in the json like `Date()` isn't valid and it needs to be wrapped in square brackets `[]` as seen in the official Reaction Commerce example plugin `/private/data/Products.json` here:

- https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-example-plugin/blob/master/private/data/Products.json

The file I was trying to import was converted from Mongo's `bsondump` tool and I didn't look at it close enough before trying to import it.

Not to mention the knowledge that the `/private/data/` folder both in Reaction Commerce (RC) and in an RC plugin, will import any collection items upon startup of the server.